# how to replace a string in files only under some folders whose name contains certain string

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have such directory structure:

```
resources/config/config_12_33/en/config1.txt

resources/config/config_12_33/fr/config1.txt

resources/config/config_12_34/en/config1.txt

resources/config/config_12_34/fr/config1.txt

resources/config/config_15_33/en/config1.txt

resources/config/config_15_33/fr/config1.txt

resources/config/config_15_34/en/config1.txt

resources/config/config_15_34/fr/config1.txt

resources/config/config_18_33/en/config1.txt

resources/config/config_18_33/fr/config1.txt

resources/config/config_18_34/en/config1.txt

resources/config/config_18_34/fr/config1.txt
```

Assume we have a "OldString" in all **config1.txt** files, and we want to replace that "OldString" with a "NewString" if the config1.txt file is under the `config_15_*` folders.

I know how to replace string in all config1.txt, with `find` and `sed`, but I don't know how to replace string in the files under some folders and keep others untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe `find` into `find` like that:

```
find . -name "config_15*" -type d -print0 | xargs  -0 -I'()' find '()' -type f -exec sed -i 's,OldString,NewString,' "{}" \;
```

Comment: I got this error message: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: I have added the "-name config1.txt" before the -exec, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that should be ok but I wonder where the error you get comes from.

Comment: Are sure you included `\;` at the end of the line?

Comment: It was a space. I copied and some how one more space was inserted after the xargs. It works! Thank you very much.